# Reduce WCF Boiler Plate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I developed a WCF service with C#. Basically it is just a layer to call my business logic implementation. For example, I had many methods like:

```
public FooBusinessEntity GetEntityById(int id)
{
    //Static Class with static methods that access sql server
    return FooEntityBusiness.GetFooById(id)
}
```

So I had 10 entities, then I will have 10 methods like this. I can't use generics because WCF cant handle. I could use Enumerators or something like that. But one time I saw a project implementation where he used two things to implement the service:

1 - Delegates
2 - Reflection

The way i understood it is something like that:

```
public TResponse GetResponse(TRequest request, TResponse response, MethodBase method)
{
    return Server.Process<TRequest, TResponse>(request, response, GetMethodBase())
}

private MethodBase GetMethodBase(TRequest request, TResponse response)
{
    return ServiceInvoker.ResolveMethod(request, response)
}
```

I dont have the implementation right now, and thus I would like to ask if someone already had done something like the example above. If you need more information, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't use generics because WCF cant handle?"  WCF works fine with generics.

Comment: http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/WCF-Serialization-and-Generics.aspx This is an example of how generics works in WCF. And that is not what I asked for. I am searching how to make your service implementation able to handle multiple operations without adding boiler plate code. And I think delegate and reflection are two viable options.